# How do I turn off Visual Studio's formatting options?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

So I have this annoying issue with Visual Studio (when working with C#), I've been digging around in the C# formatting options, general VS options and on google and MSDN but can't really find a fix for this - I'm assuming there's just a checkbox somewhere and I've just overlooked it. Here it is:

I like to format my code like this:

```
Type var2    = new Type();
Type someVar = new Type();
```

But visual studio insists on formatting it like this, whenever the automatic format feature is applied:

```
Type var2 = new Type();
Type someVar = new Type();
```

Where do I turn this annoying feature **off**?

Comment: I consider this to be a bad practice. It's not consistent, some  use spaces and tabs (I know you can fix this, but it's still an extra factor), and hard to maintain. If a new variable with a longer name must be added, you have to adjust the others as well. The extra readability YOU get, doesnt weigh up to the exta hassle, imo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Formatting Options, In the Spacing section:

there is an option called **'Ignore spaces in declaration statements'**.
Check that option, and VS.NET will not re-format the declarations that you make.

So, this should work:

```
int i      = 5;
int melp   = 4;
```

But, when you do this, VS.NET will still reformat your code:

```
int i;
int melp;

i    = 5;
melp = 4;
```

will become:

```
int i;
int melp;

i = 5;
melp = 4;
```

So, it is really only in declaration statements that VS.NET will ignore the extra spacing you provide.

Answer (score 4):

Tools|Options|C#|Formatting

I. Ignore spaces in declaration statements <<-- check this

AND

II. Set spacing for operators
      Insert space...
      Ignore spaces ...       <<-- check this

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> "Keep Tabs"

Comment: If you declarations are spaced using tabs then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Tools|Options|C#|Formatting