# auto formatting new line after inline block comment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, autoformatting, block-comments

Visual Studio autoformat places a new line after all block comments - at least the one I am using. It does so obviously only for those comments, which come first on a line.

```
/*mark1*/ double[] a = new /*mark2*/ double[100];
```

is formated to:

```
/*mark1*/ 
double[] a = new /*mark2*/ double[100];
```

Since I am using inline block comments as marks for a code replication tool, I want to disable that 'feature' for *all* block comments. Auto format should simply ignore them.

```
/*mark1*/ double[] a = new /*mark2*/ double[100];
```

should not break the line while auto formatting.

Is this possible and how? I tried everything in the "New Lines" section in the C# formatting settings, but without luck.

Comment: see this duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626439/how-do-i-turn-off-visual-studios-formatting-options

Comment: @Adeel: please read the question. This is not a duplicate. I am not asking for "ignoring spaces in declaration statements", but not to insert new lines after inline block comments.

Comment: oops :( its my fault. sorry SO Users

Comment: @Adeel: you must have true fans, voting up such a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0055
        /*mark1*/ double[] a = new /*mark2*/ double[100];
#pragma warning restore IDE0055
```

Hackish way, because there is no proper way to set up formatting for this, so why not just temporarly disable formatting.
You can also use `#pragma warning disable format`