# Visual Studio 2010 - C# - "Ignore spaces in declaration statements" not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text-formatting

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and have statements that look like this:

```
a = 1;
ab = 12;
abc = 123;
etc...
```

which I would very much like to turn into this:

```
a   = 1;
ab  = 12;
abc = 123;
etc...
```

without Visual Studio then turning them back to to the first example when ending the statement with a semi-colon or Pressing Ctrl-K + F (Format selected lines).

I have checked the box Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing->"Ignore spaces in declaration statements" but it doesn't help. It only helps for real declaration when I am creating a new variable. That is, it works on the following block:

```
int a   = 1;
int ab  = 12;
int abc = 123;
etc...
```

But I really (also) need an option "Ignore spaces in assignment statements". How do a I do that?
I have tried to install "Align Assignment" (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cc34d69-c6f1-41e3-ac6e-5de071b3edc8) and sure enough, it aligns the rows, but then Visual Studio de-aligns them automatically when formatting the text file or editing the rows.

Comment: Personally I found it much more useful to learn new IDE rules, than to pass my old IDE experience over years through. For me first example looks natural and accepted, while second.. I would [reformat it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26506563/edit), but then your question subject get lost ;)

Comment: @Sinatr I don't know what you mean with "learn new IDE rules" but I am bound to VS2010 version at the moment in this project. Also, when having many lines of code with long assignments it really does wonders when one can align them like I want to. So, I do not know why one would want to reformat it?

Comment: I was aligning variables like this back in old days (Borland C 3.1). Since VS I stick to auto-formatting offered by its editor. Few years later I got used to it. It might be easier to get used to it than to *fight the system*, that's what I mean. Btw, you are not [alone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/626439/1997232). But be ready whenever copy/pasting your code into public what it gets reformatted =P

Comment: @Sinatr Ok, I get your point, but putting the formatting preferences aside, in my post I merely wonder why it behaves like it does; since there is that setting in Visual Studio called "Ignore spaces in assignment statement" and it works for my third example, but not for the second. So I was wondering if I had missed some option for the second example or how one should do to get the alignment that I want?

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.codealignment.com/ ? I find it makes my life easier when dealing with all my alignment needs :)

Comment: @Noctis Thanks for the tip! No, I have not tried it yet. But the thing is that I have found a tool that re-aligns the code as I want to, but Visual Studio reverts the alignment as I mention in my post in the lower section.

Comment: so, when does it actually "deformat" it ? straight away? when you save, close brackets, put a `;` ?

Comment: @Noctis I cite my original post: "[...] without Visual Studio then turning them back to to the first example when ending the statement with a semi-colon or Pressing Ctrl-K + F (Format selected lines)."
That is, as soon as I edit the line or re-format the code by Ctrl+K Ctrl+F or if I simply edit the indented line of code and put a semicolon it immediately breaks the indentation.

Answer (score 8):

This was answered in a duplicate question that is linked above. I have verified that it works. The important missing part is the operator option. Since I can't comment and vote, here is the solution copied from [viktorcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925500/viktorcpp):

Tools|Options|C#|Formatting

I. Ignore spaces in declaration statements <<-- check this

AND

II. Set spacing for operators
Insert space...
Ignore spaces ... <<-- check this

Comment: This mostly works, but for ternary operators (`myVar = someVarIsTrue ? 1 : 0`) everything after the `?` will no longer be aligned on save (but using these options, everything before it *is* aligned)

Answer (score 0):

The settings that I'm aware of would be to automatically format on `;`, `}` and `paste`.
You can disable them to avoid formatting on those.

This is from VS 2013, but I'm sure 2010 will have something similar:

[image: VS settings]

I usually don't have issues with reformatting, since I'll first write the code / method, and then simply use the code alignment to align on a specific `=` or `.` or `,`.

You'll have to avoid the formatting (CTRL-K,F), but I can't remember really needing it on a daily basis (unless I get some really bad code from somewhere ...)

Other than that, I usually use Sublime for some other specific uses since I love the multi cursors, and once you get use to it, it's sometimes easier to paste into sublime, edit, and paste back.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, disabling would probably fix the issue, but I don't want to diasble since I want it to do the re-formatting on semi-colon etc - just not ruin my aligned assignments.

Also, this is very much my case: going through massive amounts of code where I really would like to do (Ctrl+K,F) often without it ruining the alignments.

In the options I have enabled the Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing->"Ignore spaces in declaration statements" but I can not figure out why it is only "declaration statements". I want exactly the same functionality but "Assignment statements" as well :/

Comment: sounds like you have a niche for writing an extension for VS then :) No idea how easy it'll be though... hopefully somebody else knows more and can shed light on your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help though, you are right, I have been thinking of writing an extension, but right now there's no real time available for it. There must be progress made continuousely to the code.

Comment: been there, done that, i have the equivalent of the dead aeroplanes junk yards you see in movies, only it's a folder with projects i wanted to do :)